# Multidataset, multidimensional array of objects in JS and in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am stuck with the problem. Is there a difference between arrays in examples below:

This one in React:

```
const multiDataSet = [
    {
        columns: [
            {title: "Last name", width: {wpx: 150}}
        ],
        data: []
    }
];
```

Same time in NodeJS server side:

```
const tmp = [
                    {
                        user:[]
                    }
            ];
```

I am trying to do in a cycle on NodeJs server side:

```
tmp.[i].user.push(somevar);
```

It's saying that [ is unexpected. But same time in React I can do the below and it's working:

```
multiDataSet.[0].data.push(somevar);
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: React uses Typescript (the second case) - which allows `array.[0]` notation.  your first case is node/javascript - they are two different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should not be a `.` before accessing array item using index in any of the following cases.

Change

```
tmp.[i].user.push(somevar);
```

to

```
tmp[i].user.push(somevar);
```

and
Change

```
multiDataSet.[0].data.push(somevar);
```

to

```
multiDataSet[0].data.push(somevar);
```